# Is non-observable model object in the ViewModel against MVVM architecture in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm

I have a non-observable model class called `Category` in my fragment's `ViewModel` and my fragment(as `View`) is accessing it directly. This model is not supposed to be changed later and I declared it as a final property. Now my question is am I violating `MVVM Architecture` by declaring a non-observable model inside `ViewModel`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVVM Architecture** is aimed towards making your logic and data reactive, that means that after interacting with the application user should see changing of UI, data output and etc. All the changes presented to user should be handled by **observers** that observe **mutable** data from **ViewModels** and "react" to mutations by changing visual data.

If your model does not change, there is no need to observe it, since there will be no change to trigger the observer.